# How to have a blank line between sets of print statements?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am having this small issue where my code is not printing any blanks between sets of print statements.

```
    print(countries[11], file=output_file)
    print(countries[17], file=output_file)

    print("Continent:", continents[3], file=output_file)
    print("Currency:", currency[3], file=output_file)
```

There should be a blank line between these two sets, but there isn't. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using \n but I do not know where to put it since my code is a little complicated (to me at least). I was expecting it to print kinda like this, with a blank line between them.
print statement
print statement

print statement
print statement

Comment: If you want a blank line, you need to `print` a blank line (`print(file=output_file)`).

Comment: u can use `\n` to break line in one `print()` command like: `print("Line1\n\nLine2")`

Comment: you can find more on this at:

https://www.idtech.com/blog/what-is-n-in-python#:~:text=In%20Python%2C%20%5Cn%20is%20a,in%20print%20statements%20or%20strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and simple way to do what you are trying to achieve

```
print(countries[11], file=output_file)
print(countries[17], file=output_file)
print()
print("Continent:", continents[3], file=output_file)
print("Currency:", currency[3], file=output_file)
```

Comment: This produces a blank line to the standard output, not to `output_file`.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try rewriting the 3rd line like this.
`print("\nContinent:", continents[3], file=output_file)`

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple ways you could do this. You can either do something like printing a line in between manually

```py
print(countries[11], file=output_file)
print(countries[17], file=output_file)
print()
print("Continent:", continents[3], file=output_file)
print("Currency:", currency[3], file=output_file)
```

or you could write it into the `end` parameter of the print statement like this:

```
print(countries[11], file=output_file)
print(countries[17], file=output_file, end="\n\n") # \n\n just puts a second line break after the first

print("Continent:", continents[3], file=output_file)
print("Currency:", currency[3], file=output_file)
```